# sending image via post request using curl

Tags: php, image, curl, http-post, httprequest

I am trying to send a png image from my server to a website via post request but it doesn't work. The website prompts me that it didn't receive any image.

Here's what I've tried so far...:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$imgpath = realpath("myimage.png");

$opts = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_POST => true,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("uploadedfile" => '@' . $imgpath)
             );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

also

```
$opts = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_POST => true,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("uploadedfile" => '@myimage.png')
             );
```

and

```
$fp = fopen('myimage.png', 'r');

$opts = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_POST => true,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("uploadedfile" => $fp)
             );
```

but none of these worked. Can someone please guide me through the basic method (methods) of sending an image file via post request suing the curl?

Btw, `realpath()` returns correct path, I've already checked it. The image is in the same directory where that script is located.

Comment: seems a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508483/posting-images-via-curl-to-a-form?rq=1

Comment: @HansZandbelt Yes, I've read many posts like that but none of them was helpful. The guy there is using `$_FILES` array which is completely not my case because I am not receiving any files so the array is of no use for me. I am trying to SEND FILES FROM MY SERVER, NOT TO RECEIVE AND THEN SEND.

Comment: well, you would just replace `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` with your filename **and** use the actual parameter name that your website requires (instead of `file`)

Comment: @HansZandbelt I've already tried using my filename. Look at my code snippets, it's `'@' . realpath('myimage.png')`. Btw the parameter name the website requires is "uploadedfile" :]

Comment: perhaps the webserver requires an explicit `Content-Type` setting

Comment: @HansZandbelt that could be the case! How to provide this setting to the webserver?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: image/png'));`

Comment: @HansZandbelt still doesn't work. I've also tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'))`.

Comment: I think your code is not the problem then, but how did you make sure that your webserver really accept file uploads on that path with that name?

Comment: @HansZandbelt I've checked the file upload form of that website. It's like this: `<form name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=POST action="uploader.php">
      <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>` ofcourse I'm sending the request to `websitepath/uploader.php`

Comment: ok, then forget about content-type "image/ping" and revert to automatically set "multipart/form" content-type :-(

Comment: @HansZandbelt you mean `curl_setpot($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "multipart/form-data");`? Because I've mentionded that I've already tried this

Comment: no sorry, I meant that your first code snippet is correct since that automatically produces the right content-type etc. for a multipart post; I figure it must be something on your server... (perhaps an invalid SSL cert?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67455/discussion-between-hans-zandbelt-and-salivan).